# AWS IAM policy for everyone but yourself

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, terraform

I currently have this policy (HCL)

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "admin_policy_doc" {
  statement {
    sid = "DenyAccessToModifySelf"
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [
      "iam:AddUserToGroup",
      "iam:AttachUserPolicy"
    ]

    resources = [
     "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:user/&{aws:username}",
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid = "AllowIAMControl"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["iam:*"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

That's designed to give an admin the ability to update someone else's permissions without updating her own to conform to separation of duties and least privilege. It seems though, that using the resource in question on the `AddUserToGroup` permission is the group and not the user. Therefore a user can still add herself to a more privileged group if she has this permission.

I've also tried using conditions like so:

```
{
    "Sid": "DenyAccessToAddSelfToGroup",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [
        "iam:AddUserToGroup"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:username": [
                "${aws:username}"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But no dice. This is just a global condition that disallows adding **ALL** users to group, which is not what I want. Has anyone figured out a solution to this?

Comment: Why not just use groups and assign both users and policies to those groups?

Comment: I see a conceptual flaw, here.  If a person can't be trusted to hold the permissions granted by membership in a group, then that person also cannot be trusted to delegate those permissions to others.  If it's possible for someone to add themselves to a group of which they should not be a member, the problem lies in the fact that they are able to add *anyone* to the group... not in the fact that they can add themselves.  That seems secondary.  Otherwise, all you need is a co-conspirator.

Comment: I see your point, but the idea is one of separation of duties and least privilege. If I trust someone enough to add someone to a group but not enough to, say, delete an RDS instance. They can easily add themselves to a group that allows that without any restrictions. As an example I have  an IT admin that provisions Okta and SSO, etc internally. I'd like to give him the ability to add new engineers to groups but not accidentally add himself to an operations group and shoot himself in the foot. It seems AWS is on the right track with the AttachUserPolicy, just not AddUserToGroup.